# Passing non integer input through console

Tags: c++, console

I have this code :

```
int obj;

    while ( std::cin >> obj )
    {
        std::cout << obj << std::endl ;
        int temp = obj ;
        ++ temp;
        std::cout << temp << std::endl ;
    }
```

When I give proper integer inputs, I understand the output.

eg. If I get 12 as input, I see something like this on console :

```
12
12
13
```

But, if I give some integers with white spaces as input, I can't seem to understand the output.

eg. If I give 12 12 12 12 as input, I see this on console :

```
12 12 12 12
12
13
12
13
12
13
12
13
```

Can someone please explain ?

Comment: Why is this different from what you expect? It seems to be exactly as expected. It reads a number, prints it, adds 1, prints that too, and so forth.

Comment: Try running the code through a debugger, stepping through each line and watching what happens. That will give you a better understanding of how the code works.

Comment: The results look obvious so it's hard to help you if you don't say what you expected to get, because we don't know what misconception you have.

Comment: White spaces are like separators, so you pass an array and function execution occurs with every value. You should tell us, what is your expectation, so we will help you, otherwise everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example includes your input.

input

```
12
```

output

```
12
13
```

The second example is exactly this, multiplied 4 times, for each of the 4 numbers received as input. The seperator is "whitespace" - spaces, new lines or tabs. It is not a "non integer", but rather "four integers":

The input:

```
12 12 12 12
```

is equivalent to

```
12
12
12
12
```

output:

```
12
13
12
13
12
13
12
13
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop reads whatever the input is, only after you hit "enter". So in the first case, it reads one value 12, prints 12 then 13 for the updated value in temp, then goes back waiting for you to type more numbers.

In the second case, it reads 12, prints 12 & 13, then goes back, reads another 12, prints 12 & 13, and so on another 2 times. Then goes back waiting for your to type more data.

Note that whitespace is a proper separator for your input. If you want it to go wrong, try typing 12a, in which case it will print 12 & 13 forever (well, until you get bored and stop it), since it will "stop reading" at the 'a' without updating `obj` - and because nothing in the loop clears out the `a`, it keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the space, it takes them as separate values. And run the while loop for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
int obj; 
cin >> obj;
```

`cin` reads valid integer data from your input until it finds a character that does not belong to an integer, or there is no more data. In your first example, cin hits the end of your input and returns the number. In your second example, cin reads the input from the string `"12 12 12 12"`, extracts the first integer from your input stream and writes it to `obj`. In the next run of your while loop, cin is confronted with the string `"12 12 12"` (since it has extracted/removed the first number from your input stream) and the story continues until there is no more input to read from.